# How to export a CSV to an XML with structured data

Tags: xml, excel, csv

I'm stumped here.   I have a set of data in a CSV that looks something like this:

```
Company Dojo, http://link1.com
Company Dojo, http://link2.com
Company Dojo, http://link3.com
Company Dojo, http://link4.com
Company Alpha, http://link1.com
Company Alpha, http://link2.com
Company Alpha, http://link3.com
Company Alpha, http://link4.com
Company Alpha, http://link5.com
```

Now, what i'd like to do is get this into a XML file for an import.  I don't really understand XML all to well, and have spent the better part of the day trying to understand a proper easy way to get the data to a structured xml file that would look something like this:

```
<company>
    <name>Company Dojo</name>
       <links>
         <url>http://link1.com</url>
         <url>http://link2.com</url>
         <url>http://link3.com</url>
         <url>http://link4.com</url>
       </links>
</company>

<company>
     <name>Company Alpha</name>
       <links>
         <url>http://link1.com</url>
         <url>http://link2.com</url>
         <url>http://link3.com</url>
         <url>http://link4.com</url>
         <url>http://link5.com</url>
       </links>
</company>
```

Now, is there a way to do this from excel or an xml editor?  Can someone help point me in the right direction on how to get the data structured like this? Basically need to group by company name, and then have a subset of data for each company which includes their links.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you know any scripting languages or are you limited to Excel/VBA? Also why do you have you tagged JSON?

Comment: json was a typo.  I know PHP, but noother scripting language beyond excel/VBA

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any tool for this specific task, because the formats can be quite arbitrary. You may be interested in [this website](http://xmlgrid.net/csvToXml.html) though.

Since you know PHP, one possible solution is simply to use PHP.

Step 1): Use file() to read every line of the file into an array of strings, eg. $f = file("data.xml");

Step 2): Use explode() to split every line in a loop, eg. list($company,$link) = explode(",",$f[$i]). Store the results in a new two dimensional array, with the key being the company name, and the value being an array of of strings of links. For example, use $arr[$company][] = $link; to add a link to a 'company key'.

Step 3): Loop through the new array (eg. foreach($arr as $company => $links){...}), and print the data as XML.